# Make pkgbuild install in user home directory

Tags: macos, installation

I have a tool which depends on some support plugins, and those MUST be installed under (in the *current* user home, i.e. the one running the installer):

```
~/Library/Application Support/MyCompany/Plugins
```

so I try to package like:

```
pkgbuild --root ./sources/ \
    --install-location ~/Library/Application\ Support/MyCompany/Plugins \
    --version 1.0 \
    --identifier com.mycompany.support.Plugins \
    plugins.pkg
```

But when I install it on another machine (another user), the package gets installed under MY user, even though it doesn't even exist on the machine, i.e. the plugins ends up under:

```
/Users/MYUSER/Library/Application Support/MyCompany/Plugins
```

with root:wheel permissions. I WOULD like to have it end up under:

```
/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/MyCompany/Plugins
```

with $USER:staff permissions. How do I accomplish this with pkgbuild ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to install to /tmp and then in your postinstall script move the files into place.

Description of this subject here: https://discussions.apple.com/message/12791392#message12791392